# Is it a good idea to put the webapp provisioning script logic in Vagrant Provision?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I have started working with Vagrant and what puzzles me, is the provisioning.

I have added all dependencies like apache/php/nodejs/mysql/etc. to shell provision script and now the question is, what should I do with apache conf?

Should I do that way:

1. Add the provisioning code which will copy the webapp confing to /etc/apache2/sites-available and then enable it (I mean the script will enable it after vagrant up will run for the first time, but don't run the vagrant up yet)
2. put the project inside the shared folder
3. only run Vagrant Up after the two above have been finished

Or should I create a script for provisioning inside the project itself and thus make the vagrant dev environment more independent so it can be used with other projects?

Comment: I usually go with #2 as I work from the host (IDE ...) and then all changes are synced automatically on the guest and I can refresh the browser to see the change so I dont need additional steps - but this is a matter of preference

Comment: #1 is the best way